# How to get file name for uploading image into s3 bucket?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello  I am facing an issue while adding a file in to s3 bucket....

I am sharing my model

```
class UserProfile(SoftDeletionModel, BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    profile_pic=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my serializer class

```
class UserprofileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['deleted_at','created_date','modified_date']
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}
```

Here is my view

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user)

        return queryset_list
    serializer_class = UserprofileSerializer
```

The issue I am facing is..... THe profile pic uploaded as a image.... But in my model it created as a textfield , for saving the s3 bucket proxy url.....

I need to get the file name for creating a path in s3 bucket ......

So how can I do that ?

Comment: how does the *s3 bucket proxy url* look like?

Comment: It randomly generating using the path......


But my issue is it is a model is a text feld but when they are uploading it is a file.... 

So how do I get that file if the model serializer it is just a textfield ?

Comment: Why aren't you using [**Django `ImageField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) ?

Comment: I just saving the proxy url of s3 bucket data .

Comment: In web I am getting the file using 

<input type="file"......................../>

Comment: But I want to know that how can I get the file in mobile...... Once I get that file I can store it into the s3 bucket and save that url

Comment: I do not need to store the image in my model.... I need to save the proxy url

Comment: what is the name of this file field?

Comment: @Hasan It is profile_pic.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request.FILES['profile_pic']` here 'profile_pic' is the input field name where you are uploading.

```
     image = request.FILES['profile_pic']
```

then you can use `image` object as `Body` parameter of S3.
Suppose you have written a function `upload_to_s3` which uploads image to S3 using boto3.

1. Exclude `profile_pic` from serializer.
2. Change your code as following:

   ```
     def upload_to_s3(image_object):
         // upload to s3 and get url using boto3
         return url


     class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
          serializer_class = UserprofileSerializer

          def perform_update(self, serializer):
              image = request.FILES['profile_pic']
              serializer.validated_data['profile_pic'] = upload_to_s3(image)
              serializer.save()
   ```

Convert `profile_pic` field type to `URLField()`

Comment: I need to add it in the serializer????/ 

Because "profile_pic"  is  a text field ...... 
But I need to get the image for storing it to the s3 bucket and from there I need to store the url in to the "profile_pic" field

Comment: You can add it on Serializer or APIView

Comment: How can I add this field

image = request.FILES['profile_pic']

Could you please check my views or serializer and help me to fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205210/discussion-between-anoop-and-hasan).